# Interactivity Between Multiple Visualisations (Leaftlet and Plotly) on an R FlexDashboard

Tags: r, leaflet, plotly, interactive, flexdashboard

I have a leaflet map and some plotly charts on an R markdown flexdashboard.

Essentially, I would like it so that when users hovers with their mouse over a location in the map, it would act as a filter such that the graph would then automatically update based on that specific location which is being hovered over.

Assume that they're both coming from the same dataset. Here's a dummy script to potentially work with.

```
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

df <- rbind(data.frame(adm0 = c("Afghanistan", "Pakistan", "Tajikistan"), 
                   variable = as.integer(1:3),
                   date = as.Date("2021-01-01")),
              data.frame(adm0 = c("Afghanistan", "Pakistan", "Tajikistan"), 
                         variable = as.integer(4:6),
                         date = as.Date("2021-02-01")),
              data.frame(adm0 = c("Afghanistan", "Pakistan", "Tajikistan"), 
                         variable = as.integer(7:9),
                         date = as.Date("2021-03-01"))) %>%
  # Imagine there's some sort of administrative data that I'm binding it to 
  left_join(administrative_data, by = "adm0")


# Map
leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels) %>%
  setView(lat = 34, lng = 68, zoom = 5.45) %>%
  # IPC layer
  addPolygons(
    fillOpacity = 1,
    color = "white",
    stroke = TRUE,
    weight = 1,
    group="IPC",
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(weight = 2, 
                                        color = "black"))


# Plotly
plot_ly(x = df$date,
        y = df$variable) %>%
  add_trace(x = df$date,
            y = df$variable,
            type = 'bar',
            color = data$adm0)
```

In this dummy example, hovering over a certain country like Afghanistan in the leaflet map should then filter the plotly chart such that only Afghanistan shows up. My final output so far has optimally been via an R flexdashboard, though I'll be open to hearing if other solutions are required.

You can use [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_world.html) for administrative level boundaries (I just happen to be using a specific shapefile for corporate boundaries).

Thanks.